# Using javamail searchterm to get one email via send date

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I need to find one specific email in my account by date, so I can get its content, but the searchterm I use did not do its job, the match method just keeps returning false and my AsyncTask just stuck in that try block for some reason, even though folder.search should be working fast at thousands of emails too.

Code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, password);

            // create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm(){
                public boolean match(Message message) {
                    try {
                        if(message.getSentDate().toString().equals(emailSentDate)){
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(term);
            Object msgContent = messages[0].getContent();
            if (msgContent instanceof Multipart) {

                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msgContent;

                Log.e("BodyPart", "MultiPartCount: " + multipart.getCount());

                for (int k = 0; k < multipart.getCount(); k++) {

                    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(k);

                    String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                    if (disposition != null && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase("ATTACHMENT"))) {
                        DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                        content = handler.getName();
                    } else {
                        content = bodyPart.getContent().toString();
                    }
                }
            } else
                content = messages[0].getContent().toString();
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();
        }
        catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Where emailSentDate is a string I receive from the previous activity by calling the getSentDate().toString() methods there as well. I tried [SendDateTerm](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/search/SentDateTerm.html) too, but I cant really implement it because:

- I dont know what is that int comparison parameter
- I can't put a Date variable in a bundle in the other activity, and can't cast a string to be a Date, so i'm out of ideas how to pass the correct Date object to its constructor.

What can I do?

**EDIT:** I only wanted to search via send date because I didn't know about UIDs, check [this](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html) if you just need to find a specific email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison parameter is described in the [javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/DateTerm.html), it indicates what type of comparison you're doing, e.g., ==, !=, >, etc.

There are many ways to create a Date object for a specific date.  For example, you can use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object to parse the string and return a Date.

Writing your own SearchTerm causes the comparisons to be done on the client; the built-in SearchTerms use the IMAP SEARCH capability to do the search on the server.

Make sure you're using a [current version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  There was a bug in date searches that was fixed recently.

Note also that IMAP date searches compare only the date, not the time.

Comment: Thank you again! What would you recommend besides date comparison to make sure I have the right email every time? What if we get multiple emails from the same guy with the same subject in one day? Is there some kind of ID I dont know about I could compare in a for loop?

Comment: Well, I thought you said you wanted to find it by date!  Maybe we need to get your full of requirements?  :-)  You need to learn about IMAP UIDs (see the UIDFolder interface) and the Message-ID header, each of which might help you solve your problem, depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: woah nice, if i understand it right i dont even need a searchterm then, just use getMessagebyUID() instead.

Comment: Assuming you've saved the UID after discovering the message some other way, and assuming the message is still in the same folder.